# sql - displaying grades for salaries between lowsal and hisal and not between lowsal and hisal

Tags: sql, join

Recently i have come across this type of query..

I have two tables

**EMP**

```
Empno   Ename   Deptid  Salary    
7012    Smith   10       1200  
7013    Allen   20       2100  
7014    Adams   30       4000  
7015    Miller  20       4700
```

**Salgrade**

```
Grade   Lowsal  Hisal  
1        700    1201  
2       1500    2000  
3       2200    4001  
4       4600    5000
```

If employee salary in `emp` is between `lowsal` and `hisal` in `salgrade` then corresponding grade should be displayed and if the employee salary is not between `lowsal` and `hisal` then preceding or succeeding  grade has to be displayed.

*Illustration with an example*

In example tables....

here for employee salary=2100 which is not between 1500 and 2000 then succeeding grade '3' need to be displayed.
and for employees salary = 4500 which is not between 4600 and 5000 then preceding grade '3' need to be displayed.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: With this kind of question, an example of output is the best way to show what you want. Also, building the results by hand can sometimes help you figure out what your query should be.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select emp.*, salgrade.grade
  from emp
  left join salgrade
    on emp.salary between salgrade.lowsal and salgrade.hisal
```

Example demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df417/3/0

Note that I used an outer join because one salary in your example dataset (employee #7013) is not within a range of any grade, so he shows no grade.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AND` with your `JOIN`s to create more specific joins.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM emp 
  JOIN salgrade ON salary > salgrade.lowsal AND salary < salgrade.hisal
```

However, the `Salgrade` table doesn't look complete: employees with salary between 1202 and 1499 will have `grade = NULL`

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL following query would work

```
Select E.*, CASE WHEN grade IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE Grade END as Grade
from Emp E 
Left OUTER JOIN 
(
    select S.grade, S.lowSal, S.hiSal, G.hiSal as preLowSal 
    from salGrade S 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN salGrade G ON S.Grade = (G.Grade + 1)
) SalG 
ON (salary >= lowsal and salary <= hiSal ) OR (salary >= preLowSal and salary <= lowSal)
```

Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df417/11